# Find a number by the decimal part of its square root

Tags: arithmetic, continued-fractions, integers

I have a math problem consisting of two questions:

- can we find a number N knowing only the decimal part of its square root up to a precision (only an approximation of the decimal part because the decimal part never ends)
- is the answer unique? which mean that we won't find two integer whose square root decimal values are equal (the first 50 for example).

Example:

if we have $0,4142135623730950488016887242097$, can we find that it's the decimal part of square root of 2 or $0,418286444621616658231167581$ for $1234567890$

The answer for the second question is pretty easy because, let's say we have 50 decimals, the number of possible integer's square root is much more than the 10^50-1 possible values of the decimals parts, so there will be more than one answer. but is there a pattern or example getting one from another

I am very grateful for your help or any research track.

Comment: I saw this question on *Stack Overflow* a few hours ago, and published a somewhat equivalent question here. It is the one pointed by @MJD (above). I later tried to find your question on *Stack Overflow*, but with no luck. Now that I see it here, the answer is clearly 'No' (at least according to the answer I received, which seems pretty accurate).

Comment: @Mjd yes, i see the second part is the same (i did the search at first but had no luck finding it), fortunatly i reached the same result of the question.

Comment: @barakmanos yes, it's marked [On Hold] because it's more math.stackexchange.com than stack Overflow, following the advice of Stack Overflow i posted here

Comment: @barakmanos: Well, the answer is really *yes*, if N is small enough and the precision is large enough.  For example, in PARI/GP: "algdep(frac(sqrt(1234567890)), 2)" returns the polynomial "x^2 + 70272*x - 29394", which is the minimal polynomial of frac(sqrt(1234567890)).  From there it's easy to recover the value of N as (70272^2 / 4 + 29394).  More generally, look into [integer relation algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) like LLL and PSLQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first try would be to compute the continued fraction of the given decimals as far as precision can carry us and see if we can "guess" a repeating pattern.
For example $$0.414213\ldots = \frac1{2+\frac1{2+\frac1{2+\ddots}}}$$
so we assume it is the solution of $x=\frac1{2+x}$, i.e. $x^2+2x-1=0$, $x=-1\pm\color{red}{\sqrt{2}}$.
Similarly, 
$$0.6457513110645905905\ldots=\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{4+\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{4+\ddots}}}}}}}} $$
so we suspect a solution of $x=\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{4+x}}}}=\frac{2x+9}{3x+14}$, hence $x^2+4x-3=0$, $x=-2\pm\color{red}{\sqrt 7}$.
However, with finte precision given, we only get finitly many continued fractions correct and as in simple IQ tests, we may continue a finite sequence arbitrarily and assume other repetitive patterns. This is expecially true for large radicands. Thus we can find *many* "valid" continued fractions, among these many valid repeating ones, and each of these leads to a quadratic equation in $x$. Strictly speaking, only quadratic equations $Ax^2+Bx+C$ with $2A\mid B$ and $A\mid C$ match your question, i.e. that $x$ is of the form $\sqrt n-k$.

*Example:*
If we are given $0.414$, this may stand for the rounding of any number between $0.4135$ and $0.4145$. 
We have $0.4135 = [0;2,2,2,1,1,3,2,8]$ and $0.4145=[0;2,2,2,2,1,3,1,2,1,2]$.
Hence we are sure only of the first three $2$'s. An example of an alternate solutions is  $x=[0;2,2,2,1+x]$, i.e. $x^2+x-\frac7{12}=0$, $x=-\frac12\pm\sqrt{\frac{31}{12}}$, but that is not the fractional part of a square root.

Comment: thank you, that's what i was looking for, i'll translate it to vb .net to know how close would it be. i suspect that i have to guess the repetitive part. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

A related question: "can we have integers $a$ and $b$ that are not perfect squares such that the decimal expansions of $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are eventually (if you go far enough into the expansion) the same?"

That is to say, can it be the case that the expansion for $\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} = q$, where $q$ is a decimal that eventually ends (and hence a rational number)?

The answer is no, and we can prove it as follows:  Suppose $a$ is not a perfect square, and let $q$ be a non-zero rational number such that
$$
\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} = q \implies
\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a} + q 
$$
Note that
$$
(\sqrt{b})^2 = b = (\sqrt{a} + q)^2 = q^2 + a + 2q\sqrt{a}
$$
$b$ is an integer, and so it is a rational.  It is clear then that both sides of the equation are rational numbers.

Noting that $q^2$ and $a$ are both rational, the sum can only be rational if $2q\sqrt{a}$ is rational.  In order for $2r\sqrt{a}$ to be rational, $\sqrt{a}$ would have to be rational.  However, since $a$ is not a perfect square, $\sqrt{a}$ must be irrational, which gives us a contradiction.

---

So, the moral of the story is as follows: for any two integers $a$ and $b$ that are not perfect squares: if you go far enough into the decimal parts, you'll find that the expansions are eventually different.

More precisely, you can never find a point in the expansions after which the two are identical.

Comment: thank you for the advice, since i want the first decimals to be equal not the (infinit) last, i found that i will simply chose big enough and close enough integers to have the result. example : $123456789012345678901234567890$ and $123456789012345678901234567891$ have the 15 first digits equal